# Error render PartialView "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to render login page if user session is over, this is my code :

```
@model IEnumerable<LPDPWebApp.User>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";

    String datenow = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

    Boolean IsAuthorized = false;
    if (Session["username"] != null)
    {
        IsAuthorized = true;
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLogin.cshtml";
    }
}

@if (IsAuthorized)
{
    <div class="side-b">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row page-title">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="button" class="pull-right btn-layout-modal" id="modal-open" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#layout-modal">
                        <i class="fa fa-th fa-fw"></i>
                    </button>
                    <h4>Dana Kegiatan Pendidikan</h4>
                    <p>@datenow</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row grid-sortable">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Account")" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Create</a>
                <table class="table">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
}
```

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@model LPDPWebApp.Models.Access.LoginModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Access", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formLogin", @class = "form-vertical" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { placeholder = "username", @class = "form-control", id = "tbxUsername" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "password", @class = "form-control", id = "tbxPwd" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-submit">submit</button>
    </div>
}
```

but i get error on `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")` :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LPDPWebApp.User]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'LPDPWebApp.Models.Access.LoginModel'.

I just want to render _LoginPartial if Session is over, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `_LoginPartial` is expecting a model of type `LoginModel`:

```
@model LPDPWebApp.Models.Access.LoginModel
```

But when you're calling the `@Html.Partial` method:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

You don't specify any model hence the parent model (`IEnumerable<LPDPWebApp.User>`) is used and the exception is thrown because they don't match.

Try this:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new LoginModel());
```

It's also seems like you don't really use the model in your `_LoginPartial`, then you can even pass a `null` model to it:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", null);
```

Comment: wow it works @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new LoginModel()); thanks dude

Comment: @yozawiratama: While this answer is correct, and fixes the superficial problem, the real problem is that you should not be doing it this way in the first place. If you want to protect the view, you should add the `[Authorize]` attribute to your action. Then, the user will not even get to the view here unless they're logged in, and if not, they will automatically be redirected to your login page.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for your suggestion, can you tell me where i can find easiest way to learn using [Authorize]?

Comment: Go the the [MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and follow the tutorials - there is a section on authentication and authorization.